# Client ssl authorization on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, ssl, openssl

I`m trying to make client authorization with self-signed .

First, i`m creating certificates:

CA certificate

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
```

Server certificate

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 1024
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -out server.crt -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -days 365
```

Client sertificate

```
openssl genrsa -out client.key 1024
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -out client.crt -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -days 365
```

Convert client certificate to p12

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.crt -inkey client.key -name "My cert" -out client.p12
```

Open and install p12 certificate
    open client.p12

My node.js server (using express.js)

```
var express = require('express')
    , routes = require('./routes')
    , user = require('./routes/user')
    , http = require('http')
    , path = require('path')
    , https = require('https')
    , fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function () {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.client.authorized);
    res.send(req.client.authorized)
});

var options = {
    key:fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key'),
    cert:fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt'),
    ca:[fs.readFileSync('ssl/ca.crt')],
    requestCert:true,
    rejectUnauthorized:false,
    passphrase: 'passphrase',
    agent: false
    };

    https.createServer(options,app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
        console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
    });
```

When servers is running, i open `https://localhost:3000` in Chrome, but authentication do not pass: req.client.authorized is false

Chrome message is

```
The identity of this website has not been verified.
 • Server's certificate does not match the URL.
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Server URL is matched against the Common Name part of the server certificate.

When you create the server certificate request, remember to put the host name of your server to the Common Name part. If you are just testing locally (using `https://localhost` as an address) use localhost as Common Name.

Answer (score 2):

With HTTPS support, use `request.connection.verifyPeer()` and `request.connection.getPeerCertificate()` to obtain the client's authentication details.

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_connection

Comment: Client cert request is already active in the code sample  via `requestCert:true`. The server cannot request a client cert in a request handler; it has to be configured in the server options, as the cert exchange happens as part of the SSL handshake (i.e. before the request is handled).